# how to get thread dump of a process running different VM through java code

Tags: java, multithreading, heap-dump, thread-dump

I wanted to get the **Thread Dump** and **Heap Dump** of the process by its process name that is running in my local but in different Virtual Machine. I tried using the **ThreadMXBean**, as I read, it supports for the processes that runs in same VM.
If it is not possible from java code, is there any alternative way to achieve the same in Windows environment(it would be better if it is in script form also).
Thank You.

Comment: Do you mean a different Java Virtual Machine, which is an instance (running process) of the program `java.exe` (Windows) or `java` (others)? Or a 'hardware' Virtual Machine like VMware&ESXi, VirtualBox, Hyper-V, KVM, QEMU, Parallels, etc?

Comment: java virtual machine. I Just want to get the thread dump of some other process running in virtual machine. That task wan to achieve through java program

Answer (score 0):

You can get the IP of that virtual Machine, and then using any standard tool like VisualVM you can connect to the process running in that JVM.
VisualVM gives lots of interesting debugging features, including thread dump.